# Degeneracy in n-dimensional potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Knowing that degeneracy occurs in n-dimensional infinite potential well where two wave functions correspond to the same energy, can the same be said for the finite potential well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. Why is, say, a 2D infinite *square* well degenerate? Because the well has more symmetries than the wave-functions. If you rotate the well 90 degrees, the well looks the same but some of the wave function eigenstates will look different. But rotating everything does not change the energy, so these new wave functions you get are the same energy as the old ones (degenerate).

The same argument, based in symmetry, holds for a finite square well *if it's large/deep enough* for the given particle's mass. The minimum non-90 degree symmetric state, which is needed to get degeneracy, corresponds to two wave periods across the x direction and one across the y direction (or one x and two y). Wells that are too shallow will not have this excited state, and may not even have any bound states at all.

Comment: So they are only unique in 1-d or when no two sides share the same length?

Comment: There are two general kinds of degeneracies in QM: degeneracies due to a symmetry and accidental degeneracies (which is everything else). Repeatedly applying symmetry operations to a state which transforms nontrivially generates an "orbit" of states that all have the same energy. On the other hand you can have a degeneracy by accident - not having to do with any symmetry.

Comment: An example would be if the $D>1$ well had different side lengths, but they were in simple integer ratios to each other so, for example, state with $n_x=2,n_y=1$ has the same energy as $n_x=1,n_y=3$. There is no symmetry that takes one state to the other, but you can arrange the side lengths to give those (now special) states the same energy.